# Export users and roles from Keycloak

Tags: export, keycloak

I created users and roles in Keycloak which I want to export.

When I tried to export them using the realm's "Export" button in UI I got a JSON file downloaded.

[image]

But I couldn't find any users or roles in the exported file `realm.json`

How can I export a realm JSON including users and roles from Keycloak?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update:** The `/auth` path was removed starting with [Keycloak 17 Quarkus distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71902419/1366871). So you might need to remove the `/auth` from the endpoint calls presented on this answer.

---

You will not be able to do that using the export functionality. However, you can get that information using the [Keycloak Admin REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.3/rest-api/index.html#_authentication_management_resource); to call that API, you need an access token from a user with the proper permissions. For now, I will be using the `admin` user from the `master` realm, but later I will explain how you can use another user:

```bash
curl https://$KEYCLOAK_HOST/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token \
    -d "client_id=admin-cli" \
    -d "username=$ADMIN_NAME" \
    -d "password=$ADMIN_PASSWORD" \
    -d "grant_type=password"
```

You will get a JSON response with the admin's token. Extract the value of property `access_token` from that response. Let us save it in the variable `$ACCESS_TOKEN` for later reference.

To [get the list of users](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.3/rest-api/index.html#_getusers) from your realm `$REALM_NAME`:

```bash
curl -X GET https://$KEYCLOAK_HOST/auth/admin/realms/$REALM_NAME/users \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H "Authorization: bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

To [get the realm roles](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.3/rest-api/index.html#_getroles):

```bash
curl -X GET https://$KEYCLOAK_HOST/auth/admin/realms/$REALM_NAME/roles \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H "Authorization: bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Now you just need to save the JSON responses from those endpoints into JSON files.

**Assigning the proper user permissions**

For those that do not want to get an access token from the master admin user, you can get it from another user but that user needs the permission `view-users` from the `realm-management` client. For that you can:

**(OLD Keycloak UI)**

- Go to Users, and then the user in question
- Go to the tab `Role Mappings`
- In `client roles` select `realm-management`
- Select the role `view-users` and click on `Add selected`

**(New Keycloak UI)**

- Go to Users, and then the user in question
- Go to the tab `Role Mappings`
- Click on `Assign role`
- In `Search by role name` type `view-users`
- Select the role and assign it

Answer (score 8):

When following the [guide from dreamcrash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65200689/5730279) to export users and roles, you might want to achieve all in one script:

1. export the *realm* as JSON like done with UI button
2. get and add the *users* array to this JSON
3. get and add the *roles* array to this JSON

You can use the command-line tool [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) to integrate all 3 JSON parts:

```bash
# define the variables: url, credentials to access REST API, and the realm to export
KEYCLOAK_URL="https://localhost:8080"
KEYCLOAK_REALM="master"
KEYCLOAK_USER="admin"
KEYCLOAK_SECRET="secret"
REALM_NAME="myRealm"

# obtain the access token
ACCESS_TOKEN=$(curl -X POST "${KEYCLOAK_URL}/auth/realms/${KEYCLOAK_REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/token" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  -d "username=${KEYCLOAK_USER}" \
  -d "password=${KEYCLOAK_SECRET}" \
  -d "grant_type=password" \
  -d 'client_id=admin-cli' \
  | jq -r '.access_token')

# export the realm as JSON
curl -X GET "${KEYCLOAK_URL}/auth/admin/realms/${REALM_NAME}"
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
  > keycloak_${REALM_NAME}_realm.json

# export the users
curl -X GET "${KEYCLOAK_URL}/auth/admin/realms/${REALM_NAME}/users" \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
  > keycloak_${REALM_NAME}_users.json

# export the roles
curl -X GET "${KEYCLOAK_URL}/auth/admin/realms/${REALM_NAME}/roles" \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
  > keycloak_${REALM_NAME}_roles.json

# integrate all 3 using jq's slurp
jq -s '.[0] + {users:.[1], roles:.[2]}' \
  keycloak_${REALM_NAME}_realm.json \ 
  keycloak_${REALM_NAME}_users.json \
  keycloak_${REALM_NAME}_roles.json \
  > keycloak_${REALM_NAME}_realm-incl-users-roles.json
```

The resulting file `keycloak_${REALM_NAME}_realm-incl-users-roles.json` may then look like this simplified example:

```json
{
  "realm": "master",
  "users": [
    {
      "id": "user1"
    },
    {
      "id": "user2"
    }
  ],
  "roles": [
    {
      "id": "role1"
    },
    {
      "id": "role2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Keycloak standalone:

```
bin\kc.bat export --file realm_export.json --realm test_realm --users realm_file
```

as described in the documentation here
https://www.keycloak.org/server/importExport